# Headless testing Angular2 final

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

How can I run headless tests on a remote server for an Angular2 (2.0.2) project generated with the angular-cli (1.0.0.beta.16)?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI: how to run tests without browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405196/angular-cli-how-to-run-tests-without-browser)