# How can I run tests with a headless browser?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

Using:

`ng test`

Angular CLI runs the tests by default in Chrome, which is great, but what if I need to run them in a console-only environment (headless browser)?

Also it would be nice if I can specify if I want browser-less or not each time I run it, so something like:

`ng test --browsers MyHeadLessBrowser`

---

**Edit**:

running PhantomJS I got the following:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
>     TypeError: useValue,useFactory,data is not iterable!
>     at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:854

---

> eferenceError: Can't find variable: Intl in http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js (line 49362)
>           intlDateFormat@http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:49362:20

Comment: A headless browser is running your browser without a browser UI, `PhantomJS` is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. `PhantomJS` is not maintained anymore because of the new headless options already available.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

*As a more complete answer based on **William Hampshire**'s one, **Cuga**'s comment and my personal additions.*

---

### Short answer: using ChromeHeadless

You can just use [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome):

`ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless`

You need to have Chrome 59+.

But if you need PhantomJS (and/or chaning the default `ng test` behaviour with no arguments) read the following.

---

### Longer answer: using PhantomJS

**EDIT:** Be aware that PhantomJS project has been **archived**, see [this thread](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344).

## Setup

In order to be able to (optionally) run your tests without a browser, using PhantomJS, you should:

#### 1) Install some dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher
npm install --save intl
```

#### 2) Add PhantomJS to the Karma's plugin list

Open `karma.conf.js` and add `require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')` to the `plugins` array, for example:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      // ...
    ],
```

#### 3) Enable polyfills

Open your `src/polyfills.ts` file and uncomment the following lines:

*BROWSER POLYFILLS*

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

*APPLICATION IMPORTS*

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

---

## How to run the tests

### Specifying the browsers when running the command

No you can either run the test using `Chrome` (the angular-cli default):

`ng test --browsers Chrome`

Or PhantomJS (headless):

`ng test --browsers PhantomJS`

### Changing the default behaviour of just `ng test`

It is possible to change the default behaviour of `ng test` (so when no `--browsers` argument is provided) by changing the value of the `browsers` array in `karma.conf.js`.

It can now be set to just use `Chrome` (default angular-cli setup):

`browsers: ['Chrome'],`

or `PhantomJS`:

`browsers: ['PhantomJS'],`

or even both:

`browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],`

Comment: Anybody reading this should be aware that development on PhantomJS has been suspended, see http://phantomjs.org/ , which is also why there is no support for ES6 yet (nor will there be unless development is continued)

Comment: @FrancescoBorzi oh, true, totally skipped over that part ... well, I'll leave it for any other readers who are as lazy as me

Answer (score 9):

**Angular** provides all what we need to run tests without a browser.

Open the `karma.conf.js` file and add the ChromeHeadless to the browsers array -

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
```

Happy testing!

Answer (score 9):

Working Solution on Angular 11.

`karma.conf.js`

```js
   browsers: ["ChromeHeadless"],
   singleRun: true
```

And then just run `ng test` or `ng test --project=project_name`.

This works in a CI environment too.

Note: This is a combination of two different answers here.

Answer (score 8):

This should do the trick:

```
npm i --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

Then modify the plugins property of the karma.conf.js file, adding the PhantomJS plugin to the list. Also add PhantomJS to the browsers property.

```
plugins: [
    require( 'karma-jasmine' ),
    require( 'karma-chrome-launcher' ),
    require( 'karma-phantomjs-launcher' ),
    require( 'karma-remap-istanbul' ),
    require( 'angular-cli/plugins/karma' )
],
...
browsers: [ 'PhantomJS', 'Chrome' ],
```

Since you want a completely headless experience, you can remove Chrome from the browsers property, and remove the karma-chrome-launcher from the plugins array as well.

Comment: To add to William's answer, you can use the configuration he's provided and specify the 'non-UI' options on the command line / or on your build server with: `ng test --browsers PhantomJS`

Comment: see the edit: Also it would be nice if I can specify if I want browser-less or not each time I run it, so something like

Comment: If you have Chrome installed but just don't want it to pop-up, you can also specify "ChromeHeadless" as one of the browsers if you didn't want to use PhantomJS.

Comment: @ShinDarth the options you could use are: `ng test --browsers Chrome` or `ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless` or `ng test --browsers PhantomJS`

Comment: I am getting this error when using PhatomJs.                                      
   {
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'modules[moduleId].call')"
  }

Comment: @PhilipPuthenvila you should open a new question for this issue

Answer (score 4):

If the purpose of running this headlessly is to get your code to run on a CI server, you will also likely want to set
`singleRun: true` in your karma.conf.js.  Without this Karma will run continuously, and time out.