# How to run Jasmine tests in headless mode?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have to run Jasmine tests in headless mode and I could find [PhantomJS Laucher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs-launcher) but the project has been suspended [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/)

Is there any other way to run Jasmine tests in headless mode? If so, please point me to helpful docs, posts etc.

Answer (score 4):

I found a nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405196/how-can-i-run-tests-with-a-headless-browser). You can use [HeadlessChrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) for the headless mode.

```sh
ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless
```

It is also possible to change the karma and protractor [configuration](https://angular.io/guide/testing#configure-cli-for-ci-testing-in-chrome) to create a custom laucher or to change the capabilities for the chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Protractor configuration you can make necessary changes

Run in it on Chrome Headless using below config

```
capabilities = {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['--headless', '--no-sandbox']
  }
};
```

Run in on Firefox as headless using below config

```
 capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    firefoxOptions: {
   args: ['--headless']
 }
}
```